# can I open pycharm( on Linux) like windows or mac on desktop?

Tags: linux, centos, desktop, application

In the CentOS7.2 I download PyCharm CE, and unarchived it to this:

[image]

if I want use it, I can run: `./pycharm.sh` in the directory, but there will take up a terminal, if `control + c` to exit it, the pycharm interface will exit too.

So, can I open pycharm like windows or mac on desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to run it in ***background***:

```
./pycharm.sh &
```

The `&` operator puts command in the background and free up your terminal.

---

To make your file open like desktop shortcut add executable permission to it:

```
chmod +x /path_to_your/./pycharm.sh
```

Comment: I mean whether i can use it like on windows or mac, put it to the desktop?

Comment: @lustre, see my additional note

Answer (score 0):

1. run pycharm as You are doing that with `./pycharm.sh`
2. in pycharm itself: tools -> Create Desktop Entry
3. Start -> program search -> right click add to desktop

That's it.